# in Ipad history.replace() results in error only in production

Tags: reactjs, ipad

In react/iPad do we have limitation regarding the history.replace() function ? As during testing history.replace() function is not working only in iPads the same works fine in Android mobiles and tablets.

Is there any limitation or so either in React BrowserRoutes or iPad browsing history.?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like issue wasn't with the history.replace() rather using localStorage in incognito window in safari browser on mobile and tablet devices. Guess this is specific to Safari browser versions too